# React component className not working on one component. Styling with SCSS

Tags: reactjs, sass, components, classname

I have a header component imported to my app js. I can target the all but one class names in the component in my app.scss.
I can target the header, headTitle and d-f-col className.
I've just implemented a working time and date which is displayed on the page. I assign it a className of timeDate and go over to app.scss to make changes to the style.
All changes that I try to apply don't take effect.
Just to let you know, I am targeting the correct className in the scss and I've tried re-typing the component out. Finally, the time and date are working and displayed on the page.

```
import '../App.scss';
import TimeAndDate from '../functions/time';


function Header() {
    return (
        <div className="header d-f-col">
            <h1 className="headTitle d-f-row ">Employee Performance 
            Tracker</h1>
            <TimeAndDate className="timeDate"></TimeAndDate>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Does your `<TimeAndDate />` component support the `className` property? You have to support it explicitly; React is not applying a classname to a component out of the box.

Comment: How would I get the component to support className? I've not had to go out of my way yet to explicitly support anything yet.

Comment: Well your component would take the `className` from the props and set it on its own root element. If you don't do this the className is not used on any DOM element and has no effect.